# Inserting datagridveiw data into sql database. "there was an error parsing the query"

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, insert

EDITED!:

I am writing a program with a function of loading a excel file into a datagridview. Excel file contains product list with ten columns. As for now it works fine. A file is loaded fine. But just after this load a program should fill a SQL Server CE database with data from datagridview. Therefore next time i open this form a datagridview should be filled with data from database. (This excel loading function is to update a product list when my company changes something).

I have a problem with inserting this data into database.

I have an error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 67, Token in error = Taq]

DNA is a word in a cell of Excel file (line 1 column 3 ("ITEM"). Full content of cell is AB-AB-0192/A Taq DNA Polymerase (licensed). I think that a problem is connected somehow with space before TAQ. I tested this: when i delete space there, a problem info changes from Taq to DNA. So how can I avoid this? All columns in excel file are set as text, and SQL Server CE database column is of type `nvarchar`.

EDIT!

Ok guys you put me on the right path:)

This works:

```
string strQuery = @"INSERT INTO TabelaProdukty VALUES (@VD, @ItemCode, @Item, @Qty, @Ppcur, @StandardPrice, @CeMarked, @Description, @Description2, @Edma)";
        sqlconnection.Open();
        using (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand(strQuery, sqlconnection))
        {
          comm.Parameters.Add("@VD", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@Ppcur", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@StandardPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@CeMarked", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@Description2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
          comm.Parameters.Add("@Edma", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

          for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
          {

            comm.Parameters["@VD"].Value =  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["VD"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@ItemCode"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ItemCode"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@Item"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@Qty"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QUANTITY"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@Ppcur"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PPCUR"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@StandardPrice"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STANDARD_SELL_PRICE"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@CeMarked"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CE-MARKED"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@Description"].Value =  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@Description2"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM_DESCRIPTION2"].Value;
            comm.Parameters["@Edma"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EDMA"].Value;


            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

          }
          sqlconnection.Close();
```

Database is filled with the proper data and when I restart program database is already filled. Now I just need to clear database before adding new content.

One problem though. Getting message:
The data was truncated while converting from one datatype to another. [Name of function (if known) = ]

Comment: Yes, there is a **massive** problem in your statement - you're **not using parameters!** and thus you're wide open for SQL injection attacks. **Don't concatenate together your SQL statements!** NEVER EVER . Use parameterized queries - **always**.

Comment: Ok, any link on how to do that? Or an example?

Comment: There are **millions** of examples - [just search on Google!](https://www.google.ch/search?q=ado.net+parametrized+queries)

Comment: Is it something like this: sqladapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM", SqlDbType.VarChar) ?

Comment: Use `sqladapter.InsertCommand.AddWithValue(@item, @paramvalue);` instead unless also you're not telling what `Values(` to add in your Insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
                cmd.CommandText =  "your insert statemnt (@param1.@param2,@param3) " ;


 cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1; //initialize your connection on page load 
                this.sqlConnection1.Open();

                  // add params 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = your_control.Text; 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = your_control.Text; 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = your_control.Text; 

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

this.sqlConnection1.Close();
```

All you then have to do is just pull your values out of your dataset after you declare them .

Comment: Since the OP is using SQL Server **Compact**, you'll need to use `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` (not `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.....)

Comment: This solution is a base to what i did. Thanks. Had to change it though because during iteration i added same parameter, so had to define parameter outside iteration and just leave there value definition.

Comment: excellent, I just perform the addition of the parameters and the the execute piece in the loop. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - use **parameters** in your ADO.NET query! And put all the disposable items like `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` into `using(...) { .... }` block to ensure that they're properly disposed:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // wczytanie excela 
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    var dialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string sWybranyPlik;

    if (dialogResult  == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      sWybranyPlik = openFileDialog1.FileName;

      try
      {
         using(OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + sWybranyPlik + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"))
         {
         OleDbDataAdapter OleDBAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Tabelle1$]", ExcelConnection);

         OleDBAdapter.Fill(DtSet.Tables[0]);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];

             -- recommendation: always explicitly *specify* the columns of the table
             -- that you're inserting into
         string strQuery = @"INSERT INTO TabelaProdukty(col1, col2, col3,....., colN)
                     VALUES (@VD, @ItemCode, @Item, @Qty, @Ppcur, @StandardPrice, @CeMarked, @Description, @Description2, @Edma)";

                 using(sqlconnection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\BMGRP\\Oferty BMGRP\\Oferty BMGRP\\bin\\Debug\\BazaDanych.sdf"))
         using(SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand(strQuery, sqlconnection))
         {
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VD", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["VD"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ItemCode"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QUANTITY"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ppcur", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PPCUR"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StandardPrice", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STANDARD_SELL_PRICE"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CeMarked", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CE-MARKED"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description2", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM_DESCRIPTION2"].Value);
             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edma", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EDMA"].Value);

             sqlconnection.Open();
             comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
             sqlconnection.Close();
         }

         ExcelConnection.Close();
          }      
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used this solution also as a basis.